# MySQL / AJAX / jQuery Autocomplete

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am attempting to make a search bar on the top of my website which will search through a table with relatively low stringency. Basically, the user types a key word corresponding to one of the three columns below and they will send an AJAX request and a link to the corresponding page will pop up in my div.

[image]

For some reason, no matter what I try, I can't get the "5gooper" entry to show up. When I search "a" or "aa", the other two show up but no combination of letters will return the 5gooper entry. Here is my code:

**PHP**

```
$searchquery = $_POST['searchquery'];
$searchquery2 =  "%$searchquery%";

$query = "SELECT * FROM data WHERE 
                        name LIKE '$searchquery2'
                        OR author LIKE '$searchquery2'
                        OR project LIKE '$searchquery2'
                        OR protocol LIKE '$searchquery2'
                        ORDER BY DATE DESC LIMIT 20";
```

**AJAX**

```
$('#sbar').keyup(function(){

    var query = $(this).val();

    $.ajax
        ({
    url: "autocomplete.php", 
    data: {searchquery: query},
    type: 'POST',
    success: function(data){
        $('#acd').html(data); //acd stands for auto complete div
                            }
        });     

});
```

Any idea as to why the search isn't entirely working? Even with flanking '%'s, it won't find the gooper entry, no matter what I type.

Thanks

Comment: This is vulnerable to SQL Injection

Comment: Yeah, I'm getting my barebones done first then worrying about security later.

Comment: I usually code with security in mind to prevent anything from slipping past me in the end.

Comment: Yeah, probably a good idea, I'm just very slow when it comes to programming so I'm trying to make each element of this site a mini-project then will do a lot of reading about creating a secure site later on. What I'm doing right now is more a 'proof of concept' thing for a business anyways so security isn't a huge issue because it wont be public.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I would do it:

```
$('#search-input input[type=text]').on('keyup', function(){

    var input = $('#search-input input[type=text]').val();
    var $name = $.trim(input); 

    if($name.length > 3 && $name.length < 25) {

        delay(function() {

            var url = encodeURI("search/" + $name);

            $.ajax({

                url: url,
                type: "get",
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(data) {

                   console.log(data);

                }

            });

        }, 500);

    }

});
```

and my delay function

```
var delay = (function() {
  var timer = 0;
  return function(callback, ms){
    clearTimeout (timer);
    timer = setTimeout(callback, ms);
  };
})();
```

This is for `GET` and can easily be changed to `POST`. It's equipped with spam protection by executing the ajax call every 500 ms and the character range can be adjusted to work after x characters but no more than x characters.

Comment: Can you explain what's going on in your JS after and including "delay(function() {.......});"? The var url and encodeURI along with the "search/" is confusing me :)

Comment: That's only if you're using a `GET` request. All that is is saying that is a valid URL. So if I typed `hello` that would output `search/hello`